# Re-instantiate Class variable in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart, instantiation

At the beginning of my app I have a global variable `gameData` which is declared and instantiated as:

```
GameData gameData = GameData();
```

Later I want to clear the `gameData` variable and re-instantiate/reset the variable with a clean instance of `GameData`.  I do this by calling a function:

```
void ResetGameData() {
  gameData = new GameData();
}
```

But that's not clearing the `gameData` variable. All the old values are remaining. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That should work.  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was instantiating a class within a class, and that syntax was incorrect so the sub-class was retaining its previous data. The rest of the variable was re-instantiated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your approach should work.

If you're building your UI based off of GameData, you will need to call setState() or notifyListeners() to rebuild everything.